# How to restrict inner test @Configuration class to work only for this class?

Tags: java, spring

Base test class for integration testing imports base configuration with component scan that includes almost all packages. In one test class I want to override some beans with Mocs, but this inner configuration is scanned and overrides beans for all tests. Is there some way to avoid this?

Comment: What have you tried so far. Show some Code!

Comment: It's possible to move configuration out from test class to some not scanned package. But I don't like this way.

Comment: Have you tried to annotate your inner class with `@org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration` ? Presuming you use spring boots `@SpringBootApplication` as in JavaDoc stated.

Comment: Oh i think I misunderstood your question, you should take a look at the `@Profile` annotation.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic I'm not using SpringBoot so first variant can't be used. About Profile annotation: how can I enable different profiles for different tests?

Comment: Just annotate your specific Test classes etc.with `ActiveProfiles("integration-test")` So only beans with `@Profile("integration-test")` are active.

Comment: You are right, forgot about this annotation. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the way I like mocking beans with by essentially having a separate `MockObjectsConfig` class with the mock objects I want using the standard Spring Context Configuration, and then import it alongside my real test config. You can also annotate your mock bean with `@Profile` and test with `@ActiveProfiles` if you need to prevent a conflict there.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!test")
public class MyRealConfigClass {

    @Bean
    public YetAnotherClass yetAnotherClass() {
        return new YetAnotherClass();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class MockObjectsConfig {

    @Bean
    public YetAnotherClass yetAnotherClass() {
        Mockito.mock(YetAnotherClass.class); // and add any thenReturns, answers, etc. here
    }    
}
```

Then include it in your test like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyRealConfigClass.class, MockObjectsConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
public class MyJunitTest {

    @Autowired
    private RestController restController;

}
```

Then your mock bean will be used and not the real one from the **production** config.

Comment: Thanks, forget about @ActiveProfiles annotation